# Add more weight to components of equation?

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics, curves, elementary-functions

I'm not sure how to ask this question, so please bear with me. I'm not even sure if it's possible with just this information. This is the only information that we received.

I'm using this equation for rankings:

$$\text{CONSLOSS}+{\text{LOSS}} - {\frac {\text{IN}/\text{OUT}} {\text{IN}/\text{OUT}  + 1}}$$

```
        CONSLOSS    LOSS   MONTHS    IN   OUT   Rank formula
Row1    2            25    25        30   10    26.25
Row2    1            1     25        8000 1000  1.111
Row3    0            0     25        100  90    -0.526315789
```

Based on the result, Row1 is worse off, which is correct mathematically-speaking.

But for payroll, Row2 is worse than Row1 because in 25 months, it only last 1 month, and it's the last month of the sample. They're adding more weight to that one loss and the fact that their IN & OUT churn is much greater than the other two rows.

I guess my question is... is there a way I can add *something to this formula* so that `Row2` ends up having a higher value because a component was given more weight?

Comment: The thing you call an increasing function is increasing as a function of $x,$ or of $A$ or $B,$ or of $x/y,$ and is decreasing as a function of $y.$ Which of these did you have in mind when you called it an increasing function?

Comment: The increasing function was applied for some extreme cases that we had, where IN/OUT was greater than 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can experiment with two constants $A$ and $B$. Modify your formula so that you multiply LOSS by $A$ and the fraction by $B$.

Play around until you have values for $A$ and $B$ that make the output look right for your purpose.

These are easy experiments to do in Excel.

Comment: It is a bit unfortunate that in the original post, the nonconstant observations `CONSLOSS` and `LOSS` were called $A$ and $B$ respectively, which you now propose as weighting factors.  However this is essentially the easy solution, if there is one, so I upvoted.  The body of the Question introduces some consideration of `MONTHS` that as Readers I don't think we can appreciate.

Comment: @hardmath If I'd seen the original post I'd not have so named the weights. I ignored MONTHS since that field is constant in the data given. Presumably there should be some per MONTH term in the general case, but there's no way to guess. There are also other ways to perturb the last term, perhaps by replaciing the $1$ by a tunable constant. But we've no way to know what the OP really wants to see.